# Can I GET a list of images not in an album without a bearer token?

Tags: imgur

I am writing a simple extension for phpBB.  It will list thumbnails of images below the posting window to make insertion into the message easy.  The user will setup their flickr nsid (with the help of a lookup function) and/or imgur username.  When they create or reply to a thread a window is shown below the message window.  They can select from any image host they have setup.  A second drop-down will show the user's public albums.  I would like to show all of the users 25 most recent images by default.  If they want something more specific they can select an album from the list.

I can populate the album list and get a listing of the images in that album without using a bearer token.  I would like to be able to do the same for all public images not in an album.  It doesn't make sense that this would require additional authorization.  Is this something that is possible?  I would really like to stick to the un-authed methods.

Thanks.